# Association Rules Data format

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am trying to run  an association rule model using the apriori algorithm in the R program.  I have my data in either txt file format or in csv file format.  My data generally looks like this.

```
a, b, c, d,
e, f, g, h,
i, j, k, l, 
(etc.)
```

The data is usually read into `R`

```
read.transactions("Trial.txt")
transactions in sparse format with
 138 transactions (rows) and
 217 items (columns)
```

However when I try to run the apriori algorithm, I get an error.

```
> m1 <- apriori("Trial.txt")
Error in as(data, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “transactions”
```

I think there is a problem with how I am entering the data into R.  I have tried the methods for removing duplicates and this does not appear to work.  How should I enter this data into R to run the model?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation `?apriori`: the first argument (`data`) is expected to be an "*object of class transactions or any data structure which can be coerced into transactions*". You provided a character vector of length 1, which cannot be coerced into a transactions object. Here's an example:

```
writeLines("a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l", tf <- tempfile())
library(arules)
(trans <- read.transactions(tf, sep=","))
# transactions in sparse format with
#  3 transactions (rows) and
#  12 items (columns)
m1 <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(confidence = 1, minlen = 4))
head(inspect(m1))
#       lhs    rhs   support confidence lift
# 1 {a,b,c} => {d} 0.3333333          1    3
# 2 {a,b,d} => {c} 0.3333333          1    3
# 3 {a,c,d} => {b} 0.3333333          1    3
# 4 {b,c,d} => {a} 0.3333333          1    3
# 5 {e,f,g} => {h} 0.3333333          1    3
# 6 {e,f,h} => {g} 0.3333333          1    3
```